# Excel search for string

Tags: excel, function

What is function to search for a string in an excel cell and have another string displayed in the second cell whether that string was found in the first cell.

For example:

Cell A1 contains text: "This is some sample text"

I have a list of predefined strings in a column in another sheet, and they are: "text, sample1, sample2, string" (all in separate cells)

Cell A2 should then display: text - because the word text exists in cell A1, so basically need to match only specific words from one cell to the other. In real life A1 will have many words but I need to just look for one.

Comment: Do you want to match only whole words or any string of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list of 4 text strings are in Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4 then try this formula in A2

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4,A1),Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4)`

for your example that will return "text". In general it will return the **last** matching word from that range

.....you can also modify that slightly to match whole words only

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4&" "," "&A1&" "),Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4)`

assumes only spaces between words (no punctuation)

Comment: Can you explain what the 2^15 (32k) is used for? Never seen this used within an Excel formula before!

Comment: =LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4,A1),Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4) works fine when there is a space between the words but it will not find the word when it is of format This|is|sample|text which is required at times. How to change it for that?

Comment: @bendataclear You need the lookup value to be a large number, larger than any number in the array returned by `SEARCH(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4,A1)` - as the maximum number of characters in a cell is 2^15 -1 (32,767) then 2^15 will fulfil that requirement

Comment: @sd_dracula try this version of my second suggestion `=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH("|"&Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4&"|","|"&A1&"|"),Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4)`

Comment: @sd_dracula Replace the reference to A1 with SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|"," ")? That ought to work as long as you're not using a | as a character within a word.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each string you're entering in Sheet1 is checking if it contains a string from any cell in Sheet2. I formatted my code so that it would display the contained text in the B column, and I could just drag the formula down and it would check all strings in the A column. You should be able to easily modify this as needed for your format.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1,A1)),Sheet2!$A$1, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2,A1)),Sheet2!$A$2))
```

Basically it's a long list of nested `IF`s that check each cell on Sheet2. Within your `Search` parenthesis, it's comparing that a value from cell A1 in Sheet2 is contained in cell A1. If it is, put the value from Sheet2 in the cell with this formula. If not, then do another check in Sheet2 cell A2. And so on as you need.

**Notes:**

The `SEARCH()` function is case insensitive. You can replace it with `FIND()` for case sensitive.

This will (for example) return 'text' if your cell contains something like 'text123' because it contains the string 'text'.

This will only return the first word it runs into on Sheet2. If you need it to return multiple words as they match, let me know and I'll find a way to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a string within another you'd generally want to use `SEARCH()` (case insensitive) or `FIND()` (case sensitive).

```
=FIND(A2,A1)
=SEARCH(A2,A1)
```

This can then be checked like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,A1)),Text not found","Text Found")
```

If you want to find a range of cells within a single text field this gets a bit trickier, it might need an array formula, let me know if this is what you want and I'll see if I can work it out.

Comment: Note: that formula will never return "Text not Found" - you need ISNUMBER or similar, i.e. `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2,A1)),"Text Found","Text not found")`